# PyTorch demands image-like dimensionality in the DataLoader even though no images are used

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, neural-network, pytorch

I cannot get a simple neural network to run with a custom dummy dataset. You can find the error message at the very bottom of this question.

I would like to deeply understand how PyTorch processes data inputs and therefore built a simple dataset that gets two series of boolean values (encoded as 0s and 1s) as inputs, with OR, AND, and XOR series as targets. Everything should work with a custom Dataset and a DataLoader (for learning purposes). The input data looks as follows (naturally, only one target column is used at a time):

```
      column_1  column_2  or  and  xor
0            1         1   1    1    0
1            0         1   1    0    1
2            0         1   1    0    1
3            0         1   1    0    1
4            1         0   1    0    1
...        ...       ...  ..  ...  ...
9995         1         1   1    1    0
9996         1         0   1    0    1
9997         1         0   1    0    1
9998         0         1   1    0    1
9999         0         1   1    0    1
```

So I would like to build a neural network that represents either an OR gate, an AND gate, or an XOR gate.

Can someone shed some light on why one-dimensional data does not seem to be accepted in the iterator? It seems like image-like data is assumed? Is it even possible to solve this problem with a custom Dataset and with a DataLoader or will I have to compromise to not use a DataLoader (like in [this](https://medium.com/convergeml/a-short-introduction-to-pytorch-using-logic-gates-in-perceptron-a8779fd93bd4) intro to logic gates in PyTorch)?

Minimum working example with XOR as the target column:

```
# Imports
from pandas import read_csv, DataFrame
import torch
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch.nn as torch_nn
import torch.nn.functional as torch_functional
import torchvision
import random


# Classes
class CustomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, data, target_column_name, transform=None):
        self.dataframe = data
        self.x = data[['column_1', 'column_2']].values
        self.y = data[[target_column_name]].values
        self.n_samples = len(data)
        self.transform = transform

    def __len__(self):
        return self.n_samples

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        x = self.x[index]
        y = self.y[index]

        if not self.transform == None:
            return (self.transform(x), self.transform(y))
        return (x, y)

class CustomNet(torch_nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.fully_connected_input_layer = torch_nn.Linear(2, 5)
        self.fully_connected_hidden_layer_1 = torch_nn.Linear(5, 5)
        self.fully_connected_hidden_layer_2 = torch_nn.Linear(5, 5)
        self.fully_connected_output_layer = torch_nn.Linear(5, 2)

    def forward(self, data):
        data = torch_functional.relu(self.fully_connected_input_layer(data))
        data = torch_functional.relu(self.fully_connected_hidden_layer_1(data))
        data = torch_functional.relu(self.fully_connected_hidden_layer_2(data))
        data = torch_functional.log_softmax(
            self.fully_connected_output_layer(data), 
            dim=1
        )
        # data = data.squeeze(1)

        return data


# Global variables
NUMBER_OF_OBSERVATIONS = 10000
N_TRAIN_OBSERVATIONS = 7000
BATCH_SIZE = 4
N_EPOCHS = 3
random.seed(42)


# Generating logical gate data
## Generating two columns with random 0s and 1s.
df_data = DataFrame({
    'column_1': random.choices([0, 1], k=NUMBER_OF_OBSERVATIONS),
    'column_2': random.choices([0, 1], k=NUMBER_OF_OBSERVATIONS)
})
## Adding the logic gate results of the previously generated two columns.
df_data.loc[:,'or'] = (df_data['column_1'] == 1) | (df_data['column_2'] == 1)
df_data.loc[:,'or'] = df_data.loc[:,'or'].astype(int)
df_data.loc[:,'and'] = (df_data['column_1'] == 1) & (df_data['column_2'] == 1).astype(int)
df_data.loc[:,'and'] = df_data.loc[:,'and'].astype(int)
df_data.loc[:,'xor'] = ((df_data['column_1'] == 1) & (df_data['column_2'] != 1)) | ((df_data['column_1'] != 1) & (df_data['column_2'] == 1)).astype(int)
df_data.loc[:,'xor'] = df_data.loc[:,'xor'].astype(int)
print(df_data.info())
print(df_data)

# Instantiating a CustomDataSet object and a DataLoader object.
dataset_data = CustomDataset(df_data, target_column_name='xor', transform=torchvision.transforms.ToTensor())
dataset_data_train, dataset_data_test = torch.utils.data.random_split(
    dataset_data,
    [N_TRAIN_OBSERVATIONS, len(dataset_data)-N_TRAIN_OBSERVATIONS]
)
dataloader_data_train = DataLoader(
    dataset=dataset_data_train, 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
    shuffle=True
)
dataloader_data_test = DataLoader(
    dataset=dataset_data_test, 
    batch_size=BATCH_SIZE, 
    shuffle=True
)

# Instantiating the neural network
custom_net = CustomNet()

# Running one epoch
for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):
    for data in dataloader_data_train:
        X, y = data[0].float(), data[1].float()
        net.zero_grad()
        output = net(X)
        print(output)
        print(y)
        loss = torch_functional.nll_loss(output, y)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        break
```

Error message:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-f2833deb4b11> in <module>
     95 # Running one epoch
     96 for epoch in range(N_EPOCHS):
---> 97     for data in dataloader_data_train:
     98         X, y = data[0].float(), data[1].float()
     99         net.zero_grad()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in __next__(self)
    343 
    344     def __next__(self):
--> 345         data = self._next_data()
    346         self._num_yielded += 1
    347         if self._dataset_kind == _DatasetKind.Iterable and \

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py in _next_data(self)
    383     def _next_data(self):
    384         index = self._next_index()  # may raise StopIteration
--> 385         data = self._dataset_fetcher.fetch(index)  # may raise StopIteration
    386         if self._pin_memory:
    387             data = _utils.pin_memory.pin_memory(data)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in fetch(self, possibly_batched_index)
     42     def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     43         if self.auto_collation:
---> 44             data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py in <listcomp>(.0)
     42     def fetch(self, possibly_batched_index):
     43         if self.auto_collation:
---> 44             data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
     45         else:
     46             data = self.dataset[possibly_batched_index]

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataset.py in __getitem__(self, idx)
    255 
    256     def __getitem__(self, idx):
--> 257         return self.dataset[self.indices[idx]]
    258 
    259     def __len__(self):

<ipython-input-2-f2833deb4b11> in __getitem__(self, index)
     26 
     27         if not self.transform == None:
---> 28             return (self.transform(x), self.transform(y))
     29         return (x, y)
     30 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/transforms.py in __call__(self, pic)
     90             Tensor: Converted image.
     91         """
---> 92         return F.to_tensor(pic)
     93 
     94     def __repr__(self):

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/torchvision/transforms/functional.py in to_tensor(pic)
     43 
     44     if _is_numpy(pic) and not _is_numpy_image(pic):
---> 45         raise ValueError('pic should be 2/3 dimensional. Got {} dimensions.'.format(pic.ndim))
     46 
     47     if isinstance(pic, np.ndarray):

ValueError: pic should be 2/3 dimensional. Got 1 dimensions.
```

Comment: The problem looks to be coming from `torchvision.transforms.ToTensor`, not PyTorch itself. Edit: shouldn't you just use `torch.from_numpy` instead? Also note that `.values` is deprecated in Pandas, you should use `.to_numpy()` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the hint concerning `.to_numpy()`. So would you suggest to just use `torch.from_numpy()` in the `__init__()` of the `CustomDataset` class? And I should drop the `self.transform(x)` part then?

Comment: This fixed it, thank you. Now there is another error, but I'm working on it (error is below).

```
    100         print(output)
    101         print(y)
--> 102         loss = torch_functional.nll_loss(output, y)
    103         loss.backward()
    104         optimizer.step()

RuntimeError: 1D target tensor expected, multi-target not supported
```

Comment: You should ask that as a separate question. I posted my comment as an answer that you can accept by clicking the green check mark. This marks the question as "answered", to make it easier for people to search in the future.

Comment: Thank you. And sorry for taking so long to accept your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're using a specialized conversion routine from the Torchvision library, `torchvision.transforms.ToTensor`. You should just use `torch.from_numpy` instead.

Also note that `.values` on Pandas objects is deprecated. You should use `.to_numpy` instead:

```py
import pandas as pd
import torch

x_pandas = pd.Series([0.0, 0.5, 1.0])
x_numpy = x_pandas.to_numpy()
x_torch = torch.from_numpy(x_numpy)
```